# Simple regex with dot separator

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract two strings from one of two formats with two groups as a result. The formats are:

```
val1.val2 - group1 should be "val1" and group2 should be "val2"

val2 - group1 should be "" and group2 should be "val2"
```

Closest I came up with is this:

```
([^\.]*?)\.?(.+)
```

But the lazy operator on the first group basically makes the second group capture the entire string when there's a "." in it.

Comment: `(?:([^.]*)\.)?(.*)`

Comment: Jerry's solution is correct, with a slight modification
(?:([^.]*)\.)?(.+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this works:

```
(?:([^.]*)\.)?(.+)
```

It has:

- an optional non-capturing group that contains:

  - group 1: text before a literal dot
  - a literal dot
- group 2: any amount of text

If the dot is missing the optional non-capturing group won't exist (and neither will group 1 which is inside) so all the text will go into group 2.  If the dot does exist then group 1 and group 2 are both filled.

Thanks to @Dandan for the improvement